# Error when redirecting with http 308 in Safari

Tags: ios, http, redirect, safari

I have a service which uses `Http 308` code to redirect user from `http` to `https` version of my service. All of browsers I tested have no problem with this status code except `Safari 7` on `iOS 7` device which complains by `Service Unavailable`.

I tested Safari using `httpbin` service too and this error happens again so I concluded this is a bug in Safari not in my service. Is this correct? And if so how can I fix this?

Following is the url I used for testing Safari: http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=https://www.google.com&status_code=308

Comment: No, not really. If you have control on the server side code maybe you can use the User-Agent to recognize the mal-behaving clients and use 301 instead of 308